# onClick Jquery Ajax not working on mobile phone?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

On my web site, I have a input button with an onClick event. The onClick event simply triggers a javascript function. The function uses jQuery to do an Ajax Get call, and refreshes the web page as well.

It works fine on IE, Chrome(on my PC). but on my cell phone, it does not work. Bought the cell phone this year, so it is up to date in regards to browsing capabilities I would assume. Using android as OS.

Comment: You may want to get acquainted with touch events and jQuery Mobile

Comment: ahh... more stuff to learn.. ok I guess I will look into that!

Answer (score 1):

try using `tap` with `on` in JS instead of `onclick` in your HTML tag. I had a problem similar to this and it was solved by using this instead :

```
$("#mypage1").on("click tap vclick", "a", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //dont forget this if you're using an anchor tag as a button 
    //your code.
});
```

**Info abt `vclick` from the [docs](http://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/) :**

> The jQuery Mobile "vclick" event handler simulates the "onclick" event handler on mobile devices.

**Info abt `tap` from [docs](http://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/) :**

> Triggered after a quick, complete touch event.

Comment: this looks great. sorry for the stupid question here: where would I place this code? I am a nublett :D

Comment: Post ur HTML and we'll be able to help u more